# Jetpack Publicize and Android

Tags: plugin-jetpack, android

I'm using the Jetpack plugin's Publicize module to push out post links to Facebook and Twitter. This works fine through the normal website, but not when I write and publish a post through the Android app. I'm wondering if there's any way to get it to do so.

Comment: This could be a question for [webapps.se]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

At this time, there's no way other than logging in to the backend of your site from your mobile device. This currently doesn't work on the iOS WordPress app either.

Comment: I don't think this is the case with iOS. I'm using the WordPress app on my iPhone and each time I publish a post, it publicizes to facebook and twitter. I see now reason why this shouldn't happen either as it uses the save_post action hook. As this is an old post, I thought I'd comment as functionality may have changed. Not sure about android though.